# mysql prepared statments insert issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a weird problem with a insert statment. What's happening is that if I insert into only one column, it works but anything greater than 1 column doesn't get inserted and there are no errors displayed

This works

```
$db = mysqli new('localhost','root','','db');
$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into test (id) values(?)");
echo $db->error;
$stmt->bind_param("s",$id);
$stmt->execute();
```

But not this:

```
$id = 1;
$name = "test";
$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into test (id,name) values(?,?)");
echo $db->error;
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$id, $name);
$stmt->execute();
```

Does anyone have a clue? Not sure if this is helpful but some of the columns don't have a value under collation tab and others have `latin1_swedish_ci` in the table

Comment: Just curious; Seeing as you're using object-oriented code, why not use PDO?

Comment: Have you tried inserting `name` alone? Your syntax looks correct.

Comment: What is the return value of your `$stmt->execute();` call? If it is `false`, what is the value of `$stmt->error`?

Comment: @Progman it returns false and there is no error..var_dump($db->error) gives me string(0) ""

Comment: @Strawberry will try and see if it works

Comment: @GodIsGood Since it returned `false` the query failed. Please check both the `$stmt->error` and `$db->error` fields after your `execute()` call. Edit the question with your added error checks and the output you get from them.

Comment: @Progman `No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement`

Comment: @GodIsGood Please add the full source code to your question.

Comment: @that the exact code that I have. I'm just testing

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind parameters separately, Like below:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into test (id,name) values(:id, :name)");
echo $db->error;
$stmt->bind_param(":id", $id);
$stmt->bind_param(":name", $name);
$stmt->execute();
```